# WebView not removing progressbar when onPageFinished

Tags: android, webview, progress-bar

I have an `activity` that shows a `ProgressDialog` at start up which should disappear when the page on the `WebView` has finished loading. I put a Log on the `onPageFinished` and the `progbar.dissmiss()` but only the Log is working and the `ProgressBar` is still there. my code is this:

```
ProgressDialog progbar;
progbar = ProgressDialog.show(SchoolActivity.this, "", "Loading...");
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){                
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    super.onPageFinished(wv, link);
    Log.d("log","Finished!!!");
    progbar.dismiss();
    }
}
});

wv.loadUrl(link); //"wv" is the webview and "link" is the url
```

Comment: post code starting from progress bar declaration and calling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working for me :

```
private void initializeWebView() {
        // fix weird recursive-loop bug in WebView
        final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(Activity.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Please wait while the form is loading...");
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        dialog.show();

        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override           
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                dialog.dismiss();
           }
        });
}
```